# how to call crystal reports viewer from c# winforms using integrated security

Tags: sql-server, winforms, c#-4.0, crystal-reports

I have c# winforms application that uses the crystal reports viewer. It all works fine if the application is using sql server authentication. Now I want to use integrated I change my connection string to `Integrated Security=True`. The application logs into the database just fine and the app runs. Now i go to run a report and it pops up the database login screen.

Here is my code

```
       connectionInfo.ServerName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseServer"];
        connectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = true;
        connectionInfo.DatabaseName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseName"];
  //    connectionInfo.UserID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseUserName"];
  //    connectionInfo.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabasePassword"];

        reportServer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UAReportServer"];
        reportSource = reportServer + "/" + reportName + "Service.asmx";
```

So i have set the `IntegratedSecurity` property of the ReportViewer ConnectionInfo object. But i still get the Crystal Reports database logon screen.

What am i missing?

Comment: did you set REPORT SOURCE for report?? it will be better to paste screen shot here of error/issue

Comment: yes as you can see from the last line of code the report source is being set. Basically i am getting the database login screen from crystal reports popping up trying to connect. SQL Authentication works fine, but when i comment out the user id and password from the connectioninfo object and set the integratedsecurity property to true it cant log in and run the crystal report.